# How to increase <rect> width using animateTransform?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a `<rect>` that needs to expand its width using `animateTransform` based on a given value. The `<rect>` should also change colors as follows

- if `<rect>` value is 0 - 29: `{fill:red;}`
- if `<rect>` value is 30-49: `{fill:blue;}`
- if `<rect>` value is 50 - 100: `{fill:green;}`

**Here is my SVG**

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 613 656">
  <defs>
    <style>.cls-1,.cls-4{fill:red;}.cls-2,.cls-5{fill:#29abe2;}.cls-3,.cls-6{fill:#22b573;}.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6{font-size:48px;font-family:MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro;}</style>
  </defs>
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
  <rect class="cls-1" x="45.5" y="67.5" width="104" height="104" />
  <rect class="cls-2" x="46" y="198" width="229" height="104" />
  <rect class="cls-3" x="46" y="340" width="395" height="104" />
  <rect class="cls-3" x="46" y="486" width="544" height="104">

  <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="150 0"
                        begin="0s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"
                      />


  </rect>
  <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(190.86 128.57)">initial</text>
  <text class="cls-5" transform="translate(317.86 258.57)">30 - 49%</text>
  <text class="cls-6" transform="translate(455.86 408.57)"50 - 100%</text>
  <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(317.86 125.57)">0 - 29%</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank y you @altocumulus for editing

Comment: No worries! Nonetheless, I am having difficulties understanding what you are after! You are talking about modifying color and width, but your `animateTransform` is acting on the `transform` attribute. To avoid having your question closed by the community I suggest you reconsider and revise your question providing more information.

Comment: The <rect> width should increase to a given width (100) and change colors (fill)

Comment: I would probably ditch the animateTransform idea. Then use pure javascript or css animations to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<animateTransform>` is not the best choice IMO.  Better to use `<animate>` to control the `width` attribute instead.

Then you can add an additionat `<animate>` to control the colour.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 613 656">
  <defs>
    <style>.cls-1,.cls-4{fill:red;}.cls-2,.cls-5{fill:#29abe2;}.cls-3,.cls-6{fill:#22b573;}.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6{font-size:48px;font-family:MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro;}</style>
  </defs>
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
  <rect class="cls-1" x="45.5" y="67.5" width="104" height="104" />
  <rect class="cls-2" x="46" y="198" width="229" height="104" />
  <rect class="cls-3" x="46" y="340" width="395" height="104" />

  <rect class="cls-3" x="46" y="486" width="544" height="104">
    <animate attributeName="width"
             from="0"
             to="544"
             begin="0s"
             dur="2s"
             repeatCount="indefinite" />
    <animate attributeName="fill"
             values="red; #29abe2; #22b573"
             keyTimes="0; 0.3; 0.5"
             calcMode="discrete"
             begin="0s"
             dur="2s"
             repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>

  <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(190.86 128.57)">initial</text>
  <text class="cls-5" transform="translate(317.86 258.57)">30 - 49%</text>
  <text class="cls-6" transform="translate(455.86 408.57)"50 - 100%</text>
  <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(317.86 125.57)">0 - 29%</text>
</svg>
```